# Perl Gtk3::ScrolledWindow that contains more than one Gtk3::TreeView child. How do you disable child from scrolling to the top when selecting a row?

Tags: perl, gtk3

I am writing a program in Perl using Gtk3.  I have a left sidebar (not using any sidebar widgets) that contains multiple tree views.

I it setup like this:

```
my $sidebarscrollarea = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new( undef, undef );

my $sidebarlabelaccounts = Gtk3::Label->new("Accounts");
$sidebarlabelaccounts->set_halign('GTK_ALIGN_START');
my $sidebarlabelincome = Gtk3::Label->new("Income Envelopes");
$sidebarlabelincome->set_halign('GTK_ALIGN_START');
my $sidebarlabelexpense = Gtk3::Label->new("Expense Envelopes");
$sidebarlabelexpense->set_halign('GTK_ALIGN_START');

# *_create_model() builds the models
my $account_tstore = account_create_model();
my $income_tstore = envelope_create_model();
my $expense_tstore = envelope_create_model();

# populate the models with another subroutine
populate_models();

my $accountslist = Gtk3::TreeView->new();
$accountslist->set_model($account_tstore);
my $incomelist = Gtk3::TreeView->new();
$incomelist->set_model($income_tstore);
my $expenselist = Gtk3::TreeView->new();
$expenselist->set_model($expense_lstore);

# Add columns to model and view via view ( Gtk3::TreeView )
account_add_columns($accountslist);
envelope_add_columns($incomelist);
envelope_add_columns($expenselist);

my $sidebarbox = Gtk3::Box->new('vertical',1);
$sidebarbox->set_border_width(5);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($sidebarlabelaccounts,0,0,5);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($accountslist,0,6,5);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($sidebarlabelincome,0,0,5);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($incomelist,0,6,0);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($sidebarlabelexpense,0,0,5);
$sidebarbox->pack_start($expenselist,0,6,0);

$sidebarscrollarea->add($sidebarbox);
```

The envelopeslist is very long.  When I click a row from that list that is toward the bottom of the window, it scrolls so that the envelopes list at the top of the window.  I do not want it to move anywhere regardless of where I click a row.  Thanks for your help.  I am new to all of this.

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea, and I urge you to reconsider packing three scrollable widgets (treeviews) into a single scrollable container. I'd recommend using a box to pack three scrolled windows, and then pack a tree view into each scrolled window. If you want everything to scroll, you can then pack the box into a scrolled window.

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding:

```
$expenselist->set_can_focus(FALSE);
```

solves my problem.

Comment: I don't want the 3 treeviews to independently scroll.  Jut the parent window containing them.  So, if I put the treeveiws inside their own scrolledwindow and then pack the scrolled windows into the box, then pack that into a scrolled window seems like overkill.  Please explain why this is a bad idea to do it the way I am.  Thanks for your feedback.